# Prevent java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError to crash app in Android 4.0.4 and 4.0.3 for SentenceSuggestionsInfo

Tags: android

I am implementing `SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener`but the implemented method `onGetSentenceSuggestions` is causing `NoClassDefFoundError` because of `SentenceSuggestionsInfo` in Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4.

```
@Override
public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] sentenceSuggestionsInfos) {

}
```

Comment: Any reason for the the downvote?

Comment: Did you tried something obvious like making 2 different implementations for old and new API and then select the right one based on runtime api version(Build class) ... obviously you cannot use `SentenceSuggestionsInfo` on API 15 because it was added in 16

Comment: @Selvin I know I have to make two different implementations of the Activity but is there a workaround?

Comment: Can't you just catch classnotfound ?

Comment: @me_ that is my question how could I

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to handle an uncaught `NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
try {
   // your current code
}catch(NoClassDefFoundError e) {
   // handle problem
}
```